# I could not get the data using Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to get a set of data values from the first activity and print them on the second activity using TableLayout. I did try passing values from the first activity to the second activity and the data were successfully printed using the Linear Layout. Why cant i pass the value after I change my Layout.

This is the code that for my first activity:

```
final OnClickListener sendButton = new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayInTable.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    EditText Name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message1= Name.getText().toString();
    EditText class = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message2);
    String message2 = class.getText().toString();
    bundle.putString("name", message1);
    bundle.putString("class", message2);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

This is the code for my second activity to receive the data:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.tableview);


   Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

   TextView Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
   name.setText(bundle.getString("name"));
   TextView class = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.class);
   class.setText(bundle.getString("class"));
}
```

This is my tablelayout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_edittext">
    </TextView>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/class"
        android:background="@drawable/border_edittext"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I could not find the problem. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: `EditText class = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message2);` does not compile. post actual code.

Comment: What did you change in your layout ?

Comment: `TextView` missing `layout_height` and `layout_width`

Comment: "EditText class = ..." can't compile, class is a reserved keyword.

Comment: This layout works well in other activites

Answer (score 0):

Don´t use [**reserved Keywords**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords) to assign a resource name.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.tableview);
   Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
   TextView Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
   name.setText(bundle.getString("name"));

   //AVOID THIS!: TextView class = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.class);
   //class.setText(bundle.getString("class"));
   TextView class1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.class1);
   class1.setText(bundle.getString("class1"));
}
```

Comment: Even if i change class to class 1, there is problem passing data from one activity to another.